# How to Sent a Parameter to A Specific Jar From the Context Menu in Explorer?

Tags: shell, windows-7, regedit

I have a jar file at this path C:\mgnfcnt.jar . I added an option to right click to fire this jar when user clicked this option. And also I want to send the path of file whick right clicked to this jar .

Added a key ko HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and none of these command values are working.

```
cmd \k java -jar test.jar %1
java -jar test.jar %1
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

java -jar "C:\test.jar" "%1"